# How can I iterate through every digit in a number?

Tags: python

Say I had the number 123, how could I return 3, 2, 1, 23, 12, and 123. And if I had the number 100, return 100 and 0 only and not 100, 00, 0.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried slicing the number using [:] but I couldn't find a way to to get all the numbers

Comment: It would be best if you could add what you have tried to your question.

Comment: Now, after your last edit, it's kinda vague what you want. In the case of `123`, why don't you want `13`? Or in the case of `100`, why `1` is not an outcome?

Comment: @vazzza You have now rendered some (if not all) of the answers invalid as you've changed the specification. Now's the time to write some code yourself and show where you're having a problem

Comment: @vazza Not true. My answer was a perfect fit for your original requirements. I strongly recommend that you delete this question then re-submit once you are clear in your own mind what the output requirements are. Also **HINT** you will need to write some code

Answer (score 2):

`str` can change the format of integers and floats to a string. Then, using the `set` function, you can change this string to the characters of the string. Note that, sets do not contain the duplicated values, there fore `100` would change to something like `{"1", "0"}`. You can use something like:

```
myDigit = 100
myDigitList = set(str(myDigit))
for digit in myDigitList:
  print(digit)
```

##### Output

```
1
0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of the string properties in python. Then converting it back to numbers:

```
number = 1234
number_string = str(number)
for i in range(len(number_string)):
    print(int(number_string[i]))
```

Comment: That'd be a great answer if the OP did not want to remove duplicated values. The OP wants something that change `100` to `1` and `0`.